# how to pass JSON array Data to UIPickerView

Tags: json, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am trying to pass an NSMutableArray to UIPickerView.I can Get Data for JSON 
[[1,"Hyd"],[2,"viz"]]
json View :
JSON

```
0
0 : 1
1 : "Hyd"
1
0 : 2
1 : "viz"
```

I tried like this

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSMutableArray *al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"the array is %@",al);
}
```

when I print al it's showing like this

```
the array is (
        (
        1,
        Hyd
    ),
        (
        2,
        viz
    )
)
```

When i Pass to  NSArray to UIPicker it's now showing. Please give any idea about only pass HYD and Viz in one NSarray. and then i pass to UIPickerView.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSMutableArray *al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"the array is %@",al);

    NSMutableArray *resultArr = [NSMutableArray array]; 
    for(NSArray *arr in al)
    {
       [resultArr addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:1]]; 
    }
}
```

This code iterates for all arrays in mainArray. And fetches value at index 1. 'resultArr' has all your desired content. Now pass it to UIPickerView